# How to replace a leaking PVC elbow?

Tags: plumbing, repair, pvc, sump

The 2" PVC elbow shown in these pictures is leaking at the joint where it connects with a PVC pipe coming through the foundation stem wall at the right.

What's the best procedure for replacing this elbow? Is it possible to remove the elbow without damaging the wall pipe that it connects to?

I'm willing to replace all of the pipe and fittings above and to the left of the elbow and that lead to the sump pump. However, I hope to avoid replacing the pipe that comes through the stem wall, since that would involve excavating outside the house.

[image: elbow closeup]
[image: elbow within full assembly]

Comment: Are you sure the elbow is leaking? Water could be seeping in from outside and running down the wall.

Comment: @JACK — I can observe that the leak happens only when the sump pump is running, and not otherwise. So it seem unlikely that it's outside ground water leaking in.

Comment: Grab a shovel. If it's leaking there, you'll need to deal with that particular piece of pipe. Make the new one longer.

Comment: Is it me or is that clean out installed the wrong way 'round? I suppose you _might_ want to clean out from there back into the sump, but usually you go _down_ stream from a clean out, not _up_ stream.

Answer (score 1):

It's almost impossible to remove cemented PVC fittings without damaging the pipe they're attached to. You can try to cut slots in the elbow with a rotary tool and break away the elbow piece by piece but any scoring of the pipe will cause leaking with a new elbow. If you succeed in removing the elbow, you could attach a Fernco coupling (see picture below)to the pipe out of the wall and to additional piping to complete your run.

[image]

In all honesty, I think replacing the wall pipe would be your best bet. That pipe might have been too short to begin with so the elbow wasn't properly installed in the first place.

Comment: Getting that Fernco onto the pipe in the wall is the easy part. Getting it tightened down properly will be challenging

Comment: Could an inside connector (eg, https://www.pvcfittingsonline.com/2-inside-pipe-connector-pipe-i-d-spigot-x-pipe-i-d-spigot-s0302-20.html) be used? For example, the elbow could be cut flush with the stem wall, say, with an oscillating multi-tool, and a new length of pipe attached using the inside connector.

Comment: If you can get one that matches your wall pipe and your wall pipe is schedule 40, it could/should work. Are you sure what the wall pipe is material wise?

Answer (score 0):

Stud pak had a great video on the various options on removing a solvent welded pvc or abs pipe.  I think the heat gun worked best.  The short of it is you'd use a osc or recip saw to cut the pvc 90 at the far side of the hub and then use the heat gun to remove the hub from the pipe then you could put a new 90 onto the pipe.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YQGHej71nWE

Comment: Tell us how it worked after you try it. IMPE, removing pipe (destructively) from fittings (conceivably reusable) is fairly easy with a heat gun, and removing fittings from pipe (without destroying the pipe) might be a whole lot more difficult (I have not actually tried that direction, personally, but it seemed like the pipe softened a lot more easily than the fittings did.)